# Why the word 'mean' in the phrase 'No mean feat'

Tags: meaning

Just started wondering this after seeing the phrase in an article. I assumed `mean` in this context came from the mathematical mean, basically making the phrase mean 'no average feat'. I googled it anyway out of curiosity, the only thing I could find on *why* this word is used in this phrase (rather than 'it just means small') was it originates from `meager` which didn't seem right to me.

Just here to see if any of you could clarify that my assumption is correct on its origin.

Comment: See the [Online Etymololgy Dictionary entry for *mean*.](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=mean&allowed_in_frame=0) In this instance, *mean* means low-quality or inferior.

Comment: Or from [TheFreeDictionary:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mean) Low in quality or grade; inferior; Low in value or amount; paltry; 
Common or poor in appearance; shabby. It's General Reference

Comment: Roger Miller sang that  "I'm a man of means by no means, king of the road."  The word "mean" has multiple meanings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An out of date usage of the word "mean" was "small" in the sense of "stingy", rather than "cruel" or unkind as we use it now.

As noted above, in [the Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mean) the second definition fits; I've also seen it used in 19th and early 20th century writing--Mark Twain comes to mind, "Tom Sawyer" in particular.

Answer (score 5):

*Mean* has an archaic meaning of insignificant. Compare two translations of Acts 21:39

> But Paul said, I am a man which am a Jew of Tarsus, a city in Cilicia, a citizen of no mean city: and, I beseech thee, suffer me to speak unto the people." [King James Version]

> But Paul said, "I am a Jew of Tarsus in Cilicia, a citizen of no insignificant city; and I beg you, allow me to speak to the people." [New American Standard Version]

Comment: I wonder what the next translation will be like. How many centuries before we get to the "But Paul told him gimme a break & lemme @people. /new ed"?